# Contact form 7 acceptance box and text CSS styles

Tags: css, contact-form-7

I have CF7 WP plugin.

I put the acceptance shortcode [acceptance acceptance-524] and a explaining text just after.

I have tried several CSS solutions but I can't be able to avoid an higher line height at 1st line and a return for the lines below the 1st one

Screenshot of the issue Below :

[image]

Comment: i think it's that first icon thingy, is the one causing that slight space, maybe if you could include the markup people can help.

Comment: Here the code https://ibb.co/cPGgLy

Comment: it's better if you include the actual code in your question, it's better to debug that way rather than just a picture.

Comment: try editing your code and past the code there along with it's styling

Comment: How to show you all (html, css and layout)? With a link https://www.universitaeuropeadiroma.it/prenotati-test/

Comment: Yup, exactly what i thought, the checkbox has extra margins on the bottom,`fieldset, input, select, textarea {
    margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
}` you'll need to remove that.

Answer (score 6):

**Use this Css It is working fine**

```
 .wpcf7-acceptance{



 input[type="checkbox"] {
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 0;
    margin-right: 15px;
    width: 20px;
}
input[type="checkbox"]:before {
    content: '';
    margin-right: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: -2px;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    background: #fcfcfc;
    border: 1px solid #aaa;
    border-radius: 2px;
}


 input[type="checkbox"]:checked:before {
    background: #000;
    border-color: #000;
}
 input[type="checkbox"]:disabled {
    color: #b8b8b8;
    cursor: auto;
}
 input[type="checkbox"]:disabled:before {
    box-shadow: none;
    background: #ddd;
}
 input[type="checkbox"]:checked:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: 5px;
    top: 8px;
    background: white;
    width: 2px;
    height: 2px;
    box-shadow: 2px 0 0 white, 4px 0 0 white, 4px -2px 0 white, 4px -4px 0 white, 4px -6px 0 white, 4px -8px 0 white;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}


 span.wpcf7-list-item{
   margin: 20px 0 0 0;
}

}
```